# SQL Server : trigger after transaction

Tags: sql-server, triggers, transactions

I have a trigger after update on table and there are 2 updates in one transaction. The trigger has been called after the first update. I expect, trigger view updates after whole transaction, but it is no true:

My transaction:

1. update table
2. call trigger, trigger see update only from 1
3. update table
4. no call trigger, because update condition in 3 don't match

It is possible to set trigger then trigger see data after transaction (from 1 as well as 3)?

My trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER "dbo"."TRIGGER" 
ON TABLE
FOR UPDATE
AS
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted i, deleted d
        WHERE d.aaa IS NULL 
          AND i.aaa IS NOT NULL 
          AND i.bbb IN ('0', '1', '6', '9')) > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO export (aaa, ccc) 
            (SELECT aaa, ccc FROM inserted)
    END
```

Init data: `insert into TABLE(aaa,bbb,ccc) values(123,'N',100)`

Updates:

```
update TABLE set bbb = '0' where aaa = 123
update TABLE set ccc = 1 where aaa = 123
```

Expect: `insert into export(123,1)`

But it calls: `insert into export(123,100)`

Comment: Please note that a trigger in SQL Server is `set-based`. So it will perform its actions on the whole set (update) at once. Can you share the code from your trigger and check if it handles this set-based approach correctly?

Comment: your ask is not clear.i assume you are asking..`you have two updates   in one transaction and you want your trigger to be called for second update only on same table` ?

Comment: If (3) results in no further changes to the table, then the table as it was observed in the trigger at (2) is the same as it would be at (4). I'm not understanding what the issue is.

Comment: Trigger runs after only first update. It is OK. But in this transaction exist another update, which updates the data. I want to trigger has been seen new data (if trigger is in transaction).

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with the sample code, because the first update (where aaa = 123) will not satisfy the condition inside the trigger (where deleted.aaa is null), so it will not insert into export neither first nor second time.

Comment: I checked my code. I added init data. bbb is char and I hope it is correct. It is copy from original code and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your problem.

However, triggers in SQL Server are statement level, unfortunatelly they don't work like what you expect here. You could probably make it work by adding some "control" column to the table (updating it at the very end of transaction and create some logic around it) or using context_info, but it really smells IMHO.

Move away from the trigger and do the insert into export table from the main scope, it's your best option.

Comment: Stuff like this is starting to make me think about using Postgres for my next project - there's so many data-modelling and application-level features in Postgres now that make SQL Server look like very dated... like how it's 2021 and SQL Server **still** doesn't support deferrable constraints, unlogged tables, table-inheritance, and so on.